# Cannot get a proper decoded json response from URL using selenium and Python

Tags: python, json, selenium

I am trying to get a json response from a url like the following

```
https://www.skroutz.gr/personalization/16890962/product_prices.js?_=1569161647
```

using

```
driver.get(url2besearched)
```

I get something like:

```
SKR.page.blps = [{"id":42507097,"final_price":530.25,"payment_method_cost":"\u003cem\u003e+ 3,00 €\u003c/em\u003e \u003cspan\u003eΑντικαταβολή\u003c/span\u003e","net_price":527.25,"net_price_formatted":"527,25 €","final_price_formatted":"530,25 €","shop_id":514,"no_credit_card":false,"sorting_score":[-4.8549,-340,-83,514,10],"shipping_cost":"\u003cem\u003e+ 0,00 €\u003c/em\u003e \u003cspan\u003eΜεταφορικά\u003c/span\u003e","link":"/products/show/42507097"},{"id":42755991,"final_price":532.7,"payment_method_cost":"\u003cem\u003e+ 2,50 €\u003c/em\u003e \u003cspan\u003eΑντικαταβολή\u003c/span\u003e","net_price":530.2,"net_price_formatted":"530,20 €","final_price_formatted":"532,70 €","shop_id":9,"no_credit_card":false,"sorting_score":[-3.45507,-107,-179,9,10],"shipping_cost":"\u003cem\u003e+ 0,00 €\u003c/em\u003e \u003cspan\u003eΜεταφορικά\u003c/span\u003e","link":"/products/show/42755991"},{"id":42901383,"final_price":507.8,"payment_method_cost":"\u003cem\u003e+ 2,90 €\u003c/em\u003e \u003cspan\u003eΑντικαταβολή\u003c/span\u003e","net_price":502.0,"net_price_formatted":"502,00 €","final_price_formatted":"507,80 €","shop_id":394,"no_credit_card":false,"sorting_score":[-4.67046,-198,-199,394,10],"shipping_cost":"\u003cem\u003e+ 2,90 €\u003c/em\u003e \u003cspan\u003eΜεταφορικά\u003c/span\u003e","link":"/products/show/42901383"};
if (typeof performance !== 'undefined' && typeof performance.mark!=='undefined'){
performance.mark('BLP.response');
}
```

I tried driver.get(url2besearched).json() but I get 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'json'

How to get values of shopid and final_price_formatted?

Comment: provide detailed std output please

Comment: That is javascript code, not JSON.

Comment: So can I convert it to JSON and get the values of shopid and final_price_formatted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need parse response to get only `{"id":42507097,"final_price"...}` string you need then `json.loads(parsedResp)`, so related to your problem, my solution is:

```py
import requests
import json

responseRow = requests.request('GET',
    'https://www.skroutz.gr/personalization/16890962/product_prices.js?_=1569161647')

responseTmp = responseRow.text
responseList = responseTmp.split('=')
responseParsed = responseList[1].split(';')[0]
responseList = json.loads(responseParsed)
print(responseList[0]['shop_id'])
print(responseList[0]['final_price_formatted'])
```

Comment: how to parse response?

Comment: @Evridiki you new to python? So, see above full solution, enjoy, and accept my answer as solved if no more questions, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tried

```
fp = urllib.request.urlopen(url2besearched)
mybytes = fp.read()

mystr = mybytes.decode("utf8")
fp.close()
mystr = mystr.rsplit('=')
mystr = mystr[1].split(";")
mystr = mystr[0]    
json_str = json.loads(mystr)
```

but I am not sure if this is a correct approach